# Have you engaged in any other activities which may indicate that you may not be considered a person of good character (see also page 16 of the guide)?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-citizens, uk-citizenship

These questions are from the UK naturalization application. My question is: if you had issues in the past 20 years, but there's no present conviction - meaning no conviction, how would you answer these questions? Have you ever been charged or indicated inside or outside the United Kingdom with a criminal offence for which you have not been tried in court? Have you engaged in any other activities which may indicate that you may not be considered a person of good character (see also page 16 of the guide)?

Answer (score 3):

You answer the question truthfully. If you are caught lying, your naturalisation can be declared invalid.

So if you have ever been charged but not gone to court, you tell them. Even when you were completely innocent. Actually, especially if you were completely innocent. You will be asked what exactly happened and base their decision on that.

If you lie, and they find out (and they will, most likely), it’s game over. For example, they can ask the police if your old country for *all* information they have about you. And that information could include “was charged with murder and released when we found the real murderer”. The facts are no problem, but if you lie, that is a problem.

And look at the document that Traveller linked to. For example, a previous jail sentence may be just fine as far as naturalisation is concerned, but not disclosing it (and it will be found out) will stop your naturalisation now and for the next ten years.

Comment: Reading how the different types of criminality should be considered when assessing good character https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/923656/good-character-guidance-v2.0-gov-uk.pdf#page11 might help too

Comment: @Traveller The second document that I've seen that is directly targetted at the employees handling these cases, but obviously is very useful to anyone concerned.